# NetSuite nlapiRequestURL to UPS receives "XML declaration is not well-formed" error

Tags: xml, soap, netsuite, ups

I'm trying to use the UPS Rating API from a NetSuite Suitelet. When I do that using *nlapiRequestURL*, I get the error "XML declaration is not well-formed" from UPS. I've been staring at this XML and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone have an idea? **Why is my XML not well-formed?**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
          <UPSSecurity xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0">
              <UsernameToken>
                  <Username>xxxxxxxxx</Username>
                  <Password>xxxxxxxxx</Password>
              </UsernameToken>
              <ServiceAccessToken>
                  <AccessLicenseNumber>xxxxxxxxx</AccessLicenseNumber>
              </ServiceAccessToken>
          </UPSSecurity>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
          <RateRequest xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Rate/v1.1">
              <Request xmlns="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0">
                  <RequestOption>rate</RequestOption>
              </Request>
              <CustomerClassification>
                  <Code>00</Code>
              </CustomerClassification>
              <Shipment>
                  <Shipper>
                      <ShipperNumber>xxxxxx</ShipperNumber>
                      <Address>
                          <StateProvinceCode>WA</StateProvinceCode>
                          <PostalCode>98134</PostalCode>
                          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                      </Address>
                  </Shipper>
                  <ShipTo>
                      <Address>
                          <StateProvinceCode>CA</StateProvinceCode>
                          <PostalCode>90210</PostalCode>
                          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                      </Address>
                  </ShipTo>
                  <ShipFrom>
                      <Address>
                          <StateProvinceCode>WA</StateProvinceCode>
                          <PostalCode>98134</PostalCode>
                          <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
                      </Address>
                  </ShipFrom>
                      <Package>
                          <PackagingType><Code>00</Code></PackagingType> 
                          <Dimensions>
                              <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>IN</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
                              <Length>5</Length>
                              <Width>5</Width>
                              <Height>5</Height>
                          </Dimensions>
                          <PackageWeight>
                              <UnitOfMeasurement>
                                  <Code>lbs</Code>
                                  <Description>Pounds</Description>
                              </UnitOfMeasurement>
                              <Weight>5</Weight>
                          </PackageWeight>
                      </Package>               
                  <ShipmentRatingOptions>
                      <NegotiatedRatesIndicator>1</NegotiatedRatesIndicator>                    
                  </ShipmentRatingOptions>
                  <ShipmentServiceOptions>
                      <SaturdayDeliveryIndicator>1</SaturdayDeliveryIndicator>
                  </ShipmentServiceOptions>        
                  <Service>
                      <Code>14</Code><!-- code for the UPS Service associated with the shipment. see pg 47 of Rating XML pdf -->
                  </Service>        
              </Shipment>
          </RateRequest>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied and pasted here, and "xmllint" passed it fine after I removed
a space from before the XML declaration. Do you have a space there, or is that just an artifact of pasting it into SO?

-s

Comment: Oh poop, that was it! I didn't even see that errant space. You rock, thank you!